# run locally created file on iPhone safari

Tags: iphone, html, ios, file, safari

am new to iOS application dev. 
I want to ask whether could create a `html` file and save it in app (files) and run this `html` file on iOS safari?

thanks 
al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. Neither UIApplication's openURL: nor UIDocumentInteractionController will open an html file in Safari. I would suggest you instantiate your own "Safari" (UIWebView) and open the html file within your app. If will behave pretty much like Safari.

Comment: i did not get 'own safari', it would be in app after all and would behave like normal browser. i read somewhere that it is a kind of limited version of safari, right?

Comment: I mean you can use UIWebView view to implement a browser within your app. You get the rendering and the javascript engine, but you don't get controls (buttons, history, etc.) You can load URLs or html directly. It us a very convenient class. Check out http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes. The magic method would be loadHTMLString:baseURL: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you jailbreak in which case you can start a local web server on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView to load html file. visit  [webView class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for detail documentation.

```
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
[window/someotherview addSubView: webView];
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] @"index" ofType:@"html"]];
NSURLRequest *reqUrl=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:reqUrl];
```

Comment: but this would load the file within the app not safari??